# matplotlib overlapping yaxis

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to create a graph for my data frame. However, I got something like this:
[image]

Code:

```
def Draw_RoomType_vs_Price():
    plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))
    plt.scatter(x=df['room_type'], y=df['price'])
    
    plt.title('Room Type vs Price', size = 15, weight='bold')
    plt.xlabel('Room Type', size = 12)
    plt.ylabel('Price', size = 12)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    
Draw_RoomType_vs_Price()
```

Dataframe:
[image]

Datatype:
[image]

Comment: Aside from the issue with the type of data for `price`, you are working with a density distribution of information. As such, you really should use histogram plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated!

I guess the below code will work, but as I didn't have the data I am not fully sure.

```
def Draw_RoomType_vs_Price():
    plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))
    plt.scatter(x=df['room_type'], y=df['price'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('$', ''))))

    plt.title('Room Type vs Price', size=15, weight='bold')
    plt.xlabel('Room Type', size=12)
    plt.ylabel('Price', size=12)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

=============================================

it seems the df['price'] type is string instead of int/float. you need to first remove other chars except for numbers by using a regex like:

```
import re
re.sub("[^0-9]", "", "$102")
```

then convert the result into int or float and you're ready to plot it.

Comment: Actually the better option within `pandas` is to force it to be a float via `dtype` or `converters` inputs. Then you would not need to do regex with `re`

Comment: So,I try to use pandas to convert my dtype to int/float. But I got error ```ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$100.00 '```

Comment: please put part of the dataframe, so I can modify your code

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I got it fixed. I only remove '$', but forgot to remove ','. Thats the reason why I got such error.